# Angular: Deep copy a reactive form

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, deep-copy

I need to make a deep copy of a reactive form.
I have tried with ES6 spread syntax for cloning a form. I have used Typescript generics to typecast the return value of the spread syntax to `FormGroup`. Also, the type of clone form variable is set to `FormGroup`.

But when the form is cloned by this way, the type is lost on the cloned form variable, that is, it is no longer of type of `FormGroup`. So, the cloned form is not usable.

Here is the stackblitz for the same: [form cloning](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a2pfwp)

What is going wrong in above way of cloning? Why the type `FormGroup` is lost on the cloned form?

Comment: You can't clone types. They are just for convenience. Javascript don't have types (sort of), typescript does.

Comment: What you're doing is creating a POJO (not an instance of FormGroup: that would require a call to its constructor) and copying the properties of the FormGroup to the POJO. It's not a deep copy at all, but a shallow copy, and it doesn't create an instance of FormGroup. Why would you want to clone a FormGroup? What concrete problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: this is just the wrong approach to whatever problem you're trying to solve. Generally, you need a limited set of forms, just create a method that creates the forms you need so you can instantiate them as needed.

Comment: Is anything wrong with the typecasting the result to FormGroup with TypeScript generics after using spread syntax? Isn't that typecasting at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deep copy of Angular Reactive Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308414/deep-copy-of-angular-reactive-form)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use a function that return a FormGroup. You can use setValue or patchValue to give the same value. Some like (I use directly the constructor of FormGroup but you can use FormBuilder too)

```
  createForm(data:any)
  {
    data=data || {name:null,group:{prop1:null,prop2:null}}
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(data.name),
      group:new FormGroup({
        prop1:new FormControl(data.group.prop1),
        prop2:new FormControl(data.group.prop2)
      })
    })
  }

/*you can also
  createForm(data:any)
  {
    const form=new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(),
      group:new FormGroup({
        prop1:new FormControl(),
        prop2:new FormControl()
      })
    })
    if (data)
      form.patchValue(data)

    return form
  }
  */
```

And in ngOnInit, e.g.

```
  ngOnInit() {
       this.myForm=this.createForm({name:"name",group:{prop1:"prop1",prop2:"prop2"}});
       this.myForm2=this.createForm(null);
       this.myForm2.patchValue(this.myForm.value)
       //or this.myForm2.setValue(this.myForm.value)
  }
```

[link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sakc86?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: The downside of this approach is that any control state (disabled, dirty, etc) that already exists and differs from the default will be lost.

Answer (score 5):

Lodash works pretty well deeply cloning FormGroups, even though they are nested. In case you are dealing with dynamic forms, recreating your form manually might result in large amount of lines of code (e.g. checking for existence of conditional forms/controls). Given this scenario, in most cases we could solve it by importing say `* as _ from 'lodash'` and cloning the FormGroup, FormArray, or FormControl with [`.cloneDeep`.](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) E.g.:

```
const clonedForm = _.cloneDeep(this.myForm);
```

Then you will be able to use `clonedForm` and its inner controls as you would with your `myForm` without modifying your `myForm`'s nested controls.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {
  formulario = new Formulario();
}

export class Formulario {
  getFormulario() {
    return {
      nombre: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
      password: new FormControl(''),
      cod_perfil: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      validoHasta: new FormControl('')
    };
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<child [formularios]="formulario"></child>
```

Now here and wherever you can get different instance of your form,

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() formularios: any;
  @Output() formulariosIdiomas = new EventEmitter<any>();
  langs = ['es', 'en'];    

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.formularios.getFormulario());

    // Different instances
    this.langs.forEach(lang => {
      this.formulariosIdiomas[lang] = new FormGroup(
        this.formularios.getFormulario()
      );
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: This can't work, to begin with. `this.formulariosIdiomas[lang]` refers to `EventEmitter`. EventEmitter is not a collection of FormGroups

Answer (score -5):

You can use `assign()` method of `Object` with the following syntax:

```
Object.assign(target, ...sources)
```

In your case, you can do like this:

```
this.myForm2 = Object.assign({}, this.myForm)
```

So, what `Object.assign()` does?

> This method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own
>   properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will
>   return the target object.

For details, head over [here](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/13/angular2-deep-copy-or-angular-copy-replacement-in-angular2/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution **does not** work as it does not copy methods related to `AbstractControl`, e.g `get` or `setValidators`...