# How to assign one Form Array to another Form Array in angular

Tags: angular

I have a requirement where i want to copy profile array to profileChild.
I am unable to come up with anything.. 
Below is my sample code

```
this.frmgrp = this._fb.group({
    profile: this._formBuilder.array([
                    this._formBuilder.group({
                      ProfileGroup: this._formBuilder.group({
                        objectId: [''],
                        profileId: [''],
                        ProfileGroupTier: this._formBuilder.group({
                          objId:[''],
                          usageTierId:[''],
                      })
                      })
                    })
                  ]),

                  profileChild: this._formBuilder.array([
                   this._formBuilder.group({
                    ProfileGroupChild: this._formBuilder.group({
                        objectId: [''],
                        profileId: [''],
                      ProfilegroupChildtier: this._formBuilder.group({
                            objId:[''],
                            usageTierId:[''],
                      })
                    })

                    })

                  ])
})
```

Comment: Didn't this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308414/deep-copy-of-angular-reactive-form/49743369 ?

Comment: I think No, i want to assign values from parent to child then send the data in single object or array!!! is it possible??

Comment: You can use getValue / setValue / patchValue methods of FormGroup / FormArray. This can change value for you. So you do `const v = profile.getValue(); profileChild.patchValue(v);`. This can handle values, but I am not sure about the structure of the patched control.

Answer (score 0):

Form array can assign to other form array.

```
this.frmgrp.controls['profileChild'] = this.frmgrp.get('profile');
```

or

```
this.frmgrp.controls['profileChild'] = this.frmgrp.controls['profile'];
```