# Angular dynamic html at the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am creating an HTML form in Angular. I am running into an issue. I want to be able to display a duplicate of an HTML block with a new form control at the click of a button.
Here is what thing look like now:

[image]

I would like the user to be able to click the button labeled `Click me` and have a duplicate of the HTML block display but with a different form control. Do you guys have any suggestions of how I can do that? Here is what I have so far.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Directive, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questions',
  templateUrl: './questions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questions.component.scss']
})

export class QuestionsComponent implements OnInit {
  jobForm: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    companyName: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required ]),
    position: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required ]),
    description: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required ]),
    startDate: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required ]),
    endDate: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required ])
  });
  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }  
  
  displayForm() {
    console.log(this.jobForm);
  }


}
```

```html
<h3>Education:</h3>
    <form [formGroup]="jobForm">
      <mat-form-field >
        <mat-label>Company Name: </mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="companyName"/>
        <mat-error *ngIf="jobForm.controls.companyName.errors">Company name is required</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field >
        <mat-label>Position: </mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="position"/>
        <mat-error *ngIf="jobForm.controls.position.errors">Position is required</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field >
        <mat-label>Select start and end date:</mat-label>
        <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
          <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" formControlName="startDate">
          <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" formControlName="endDate">
        </mat-date-range-input>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field >
        <mat-label>Description: </mat-label>
        <textarea matInput type="text" formControlName="description"></textarea>
        <mat-error *ngIf="jobForm.controls.description.errors">Job description is required</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
    <button (click)="displayForm()">Click me</button>
```

After a user hits the `click me` button id like to generate a duplicate form so they can fill out the details.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're asking for is a way to dynamically add a form group to the page. If that is the case then the solution below should help.

You can use the `*ngFor` structural directive to iterate over a `FormGroup` array. The following adjustments will need to be made:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Directive, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-questions',
  templateUrl: './questions.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./questions.component.scss']
})

export class QuestionsComponent implements OnInit {

  jobForms: FormGroup[] = []; // Declare an empty array

  constructor(private readonly fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addFormRow(); // Add an empty form group to the array
  }  
  
  //displayForm() {
  //  console.log(this.jobForm);
  //}

  // Add an additional row to the jobForms array - to be called from the template
  addFormRow() {
    this.jobForms.push(this.fb.group({
      companyName: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required ]),
      position: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required ]),
      description: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required ]),
      startDate: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required ]),
      endDate: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required ])
    }));
  }
}
```

```html
<h3>Education:</h3>

    <form *ngFor="let formGroup of jobForms" 
          [formGroup]="formGroup">
      <mat-form-field >
        <mat-label>Company Name: </mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="companyName"/>
        <mat-error *ngIf="jobForm.controls.companyName.errors">Company name is required</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field >
        <mat-label>Position: </mat-label>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="position"/>
        <mat-error *ngIf="jobForm.controls.position.errors">Position is required</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field >
        <mat-label>Select start and end date:</mat-label>
        <mat-date-range-input [rangePicker]="picker">
          <input matStartDate placeholder="Start date" formControlName="startDate">
          <input matEndDate placeholder="End date" formControlName="endDate">
        </mat-date-range-input>
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field >
        <mat-label>Description: </mat-label>
        <textarea matInput type="text" formControlName="description"></textarea>
        <mat-error *ngIf="jobForm.controls.description.errors">Job description is required</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
    <!-- Call addFormRow() to add a FormGroup to the array -->
    <button (click)="addFormRow()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep) library it would be easy

---

```js
//const newjobFormGroup = _.cloneDeep(jobForm) as FormGroup;

CopyJobForm(toCopyForm: FormGroup){
 //return _.cloneDeep(jobForm) as FormGroup;
 return _.cloneDeep(FormGroup) as FormGroup;
}
```

Or

this answer for a [full deep clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743369/6085193)

```js
/**
 * Deep clones the given AbstractControl, preserving values, validators, async validators, and disabled status.
 * @param control AbstractControl
 * @returns AbstractControl
 */
export function cloneAbstractControl<T extends AbstractControl>(control: T): T {
  let newControl: T;

  if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
    const formGroup = new FormGroup({}, control.validator, control.asyncValidator);
    const controls = control.controls;

    Object.keys(controls).forEach(key => {
      formGroup.addControl(key, cloneAbstractControl(controls[key]));
    })

    newControl = formGroup as any;
  }
  else if (control instanceof FormArray) {
    const formArray = new FormArray([], control.validator, control.asyncValidator);

    control.controls.forEach(formControl => formArray.push(cloneAbstractControl(formControl)))

    newControl = formArray as any;
  }
  else if (control instanceof FormControl) {
    newControl = new FormControl(control.value, control.validator, control.asyncValidator) as any;
  }
  else {
    throw new Error('Error: unexpected control value');
  }

  if (control.disabled) newControl.disable({emitEvent: false});

  return newControl;
}
```